# How to handle edits that add their own info

Tags: discussion

How would the above be possible?

I came across this edit and few similar ones before

[image]

I have seen edits where the editor makes changes to a code or something similar (cant find the post).

I feel it should be rejected & that the edit should be first suggested as a comment. Only if the answerer wants it to be changed then only it should be edited by the answerer.  What your say on this?

Answer (score 16):

If the information added is the same as what was suggested in the link, the edit is almost acceptable.

Almost, since it totally removed the link to the source.

*Attribution matters, and at Ask Ubuntu, I consider all sources attribution-required even if they are not.*

Answer (score 9):

To clarify (and agree with) what Mahesh has said:

**Fix these edits by editing again to add back a link to the source.** (*If* you can add the name of the person who wrote it and, if applicable, a link to their profile on the source site--whether or not the source is a Stack Exchange site--that's a plus.)

Answer (score 3):

I do not see any issue with another user adding additional information where its helpful.

In my opinion it's better than adding a new answer which is almost identical to another except for one bit of additional information.  What matters is providing the best answer possible: reputation is a side issue.

In this case if the comment is to be believed the link is to a user only forum.  Though I'm pretty sure this isn't the case [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forum.php) don't require a user to register to read. *not sure if they do to post though*.

It is important that information remains attributable to the original source however.

I would leave the body of the text as it is but add a link

[source here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=725199) for example.